# What are the requirements does it take to get a Adobe air App running On a Ipad?

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, air, app-store

I am wandering what will it take to get a Adobe air app published in house to install onto a device? What are the requirements (do i need a macbook with flash builder on it)? 
1) Do i need a Mac book to test the app on a ipad or can i use a windows computer? 
2) Do i need a iOS Developer Enterprise Program (the $299 one) to publish a app so people in my company can use it on there Iphone or can I do this with the Individule iOS Developer Program? (I don't think any of the apps I am making for the iphone ipad will ever be put on the app market place)
3) Do i need a mac at all for creating the certificate or anything else that i could be missing?  
Sorry for all the questions I'm trying to find out the answers before i just start buying stuff and find out is going to cost thousands of dollars. Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a Mac. You have to have access to the iOS SDK. That's available only on a Mac OS X.
2. Yes. Or you can jailbreak your devices, but doing it on a large scale is not feasible.
3. You don't need a mac for creating the certificate, but you need anyway because of the SDK.

Sample project: 
http://custardbelly.com/blog/2011/09/21/air-native-extension-example-ibattery-for-ios/

Hope this helps.